# Picking minimum from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following table where each point is in three dimension (x,y,z).

```
  tab={{{1, 1, 0.6}, {1, 2, 0.4}, {1, 3, 0.2}, {1, 4, 0.1}, {1, 5, 0.2}, {1,
            6, 0.4}, {1, 7, 0.6}, {1, 8, 0.7}}, {{2, 1, 0.6}, {2, 2, 0.4}, {2,
            3, 0.2}, {2, 4, 0.2}, {2, 5, 0.3}, {2, 6, 0.1}, {2, 7, 0.6}, {2, 
           8, 0.8}}, {{3, 1, 0.6}, {3, 2, 0.4}, {3, 3, 0.1}, {3, 4, 0.3}, {3, 
           5, 0.2}, {3, 6, 0.4}, {3, 7, 0.6}, {3, 8, 0.7}}, {{4, 1, 0.6}, {4, 
           2, 0.4}, {4, 3, 0.2}, {4, 4, 0.6}, {4, 5, 0.2}, {4, 6, 0.4}, {4, 7,
            0.1}, {4, 8, 0.9}}, {{5, 1, 0.6}, {5, 2, 0.4}, {5, 3, 0.2}, {5, 4,
            0.1}, {5, 5, 0.2}, {5, 6, 0.4}, {5, 7, 0.6}, {5, 8, 0.7}}, {{6, 
           1, 0.1}, {6, 2, 0.4}, {6, 3, 0.2}, {6, 4, 0.6}, {6, 5, 0.2}, {6, 6,
            0.4}, {6, 7, 0.6}, {6, 8, 0.7}}}
```

In each row there an absolute minimum "0.1" corresponding to `z`,
but it is located at random position in each row e.g. in the first row
it is located in {1, 4, 0.1}, in the 2nd row it located at {2, 6, 0.1} and so on. Is there is any way to pick only those points with the minimum corresponding to `z` from all over the table ? Moreover, how to pick
only the `x` and `y` corresponding to each minimum value "0.1" in each row.
I know the command `Min[]`, but that only works for one dimensional table. Could any one please have a look at this?

Comment: `TakeSmallestBy` can be used for this. `In[625]:= Map[TakeSmallestBy[#, #[[3]] &, 1][[1, 1 ;; 2]] &, tab]

Out[625]= {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 3}, {4, 7}, {5, 4}, {6, 1}}`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Map[ MinimalBy[#, Last] &, tab]
(*{{{1, 4, 0.1}}, {{2, 6, 0.1}}, {{3, 3, 0.1}}, {{4,7, 0.1}}, {{5, 4,0.1}}, {{6, 1, 0.1}}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But one further step is also needed. How to express the output now in the form: (*{{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 3}, {4,7}, {5, 4}, {6, 1}}*).  It would be great if you look into it. One way is to use tab1= Flatten[Map[ MinimalBy[#, Last] &, tab]] and then call the first and 2nd elements in separate tables. But I wonder if you suggest any shortcut way which works in a single step in addition to the one you suggested above? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `(Map[MinimalBy[#, Last] &, tab] // Flatten [#, 1] &)[[All, {1, 2}]]`

Comment: Works very well, thanks a lot! One further step is needed, please.  How the second element of the output above is now added by a constant value say "20" using the same line of the code: (Map[MinimalBy[#, Last] &, tab] // Flatten [#, 1] &)[[All, {1, 2}]] so that the final out now is: {{1, 24}, {2, 26}, {3, 23}, {4,27}, {5, 24}, {6, 21}}. If its possible, please also comment on this. Thanks!

Comment: I would prefer an extra line `Map[# + {0, 20} &, ...]`. Alternatively `Map[Function[uu, 
  uu + {0, 20}], (Map[MinimalBy[#, Last] &, tab] // 
    Flatten[#, 1] &)[[All, {1, 2}]]]`

Comment: @Thanks Ulrich Neumann!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Flatten[tab /. {x_, y_, z_} /; z != 0.1 -> Nothing, 1]

(* {{1, 4, 0.1}, {2, 6, 0.1}, {3, 3, 0.1}, {4, 7, 0.1}, {5, 4, 0.1}, {6, 
  1, 0.1}}  *)
```

or this:

```
Flatten[Map[Select[#, (#[[3]] == 0.1 &)] &, tab, {1}], 1]

(* {{1, 4, 0.1}, {2, 6, 0.1}, {3, 3, 0.1}, {4, 7, 0.1}, {5, 4, 0.1}, {6, 
  1, 0.1}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, this minimum 0.1 is just an example and not necessarily be exactly this. It could different in each row. In which case, in a very long list, its not possible to pick each one manually like this. My problem is exactly about that.

Comment: Then you should precisely formulate what do you want and give corresponding examples.

Comment: Thanks, Alexei, please see the answer 1 above by Ulrich.